# How to generate xml file without the header

Tags: c#, .net

I don't need the header .
How to do it with xml serializer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`XmlSerializer` isn't responsible for that - `XmlWriter` is, so the key here is to create a `XmlWriterSettings` object with `.OmitXmlDeclaration` set to *true*, and pass that in when constructing the `XmlWriter`:

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("my.xml", settings))
        {
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));
            Foo foo = new Foo();
            foo.Bar = "abc";
            ser.Serialize(writer, foo);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: can we use TxtWriter to get this?

Comment: @user496949 sure; just use a different overload of `XmlWriter.Create` and pass in the `TextWriter` and the `XmlWriterSettings`.